# Take elements from lists, round robin style

Tags: python, list, iteration

I want to construct a list from a list of lists, round robin style.
All first elements, then all second elements etc.
The lists aren't the same size.

`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [], [7, 8, 9, 10]]`

should turn to:

`[1, 4, 6, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 9, 10]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the roundrobin [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from itertools:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)  # .next on Python 2
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
```

Output:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[],[7,8,9,10]]
print(list(roundrobin(*l)))
[1, 4, 6, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works with good old list comprehension. I split the lines to make it more readable. You could fit the whole thing into one line if you were mad enough.

```
mainlist = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
longest = len(max(mainlist, key = len))
newlist = [sublist[i]
           for i in range(longest)
           for sublist in mainlist
           if len(sublist) > i]

# [1, 4, 6, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware that `max` takes a `key` argument. Although I would prefer `max(map(len, mainlist))` to calculate `longest`, as you only have to say `len` once.

Comment: Yeah that is a bit nicer @mkrieger1

Answer (score 0):

It finds the largest list in `lst`, which will determine how many rounds of pops will be done. Each popped element is added to the output list (`o`).

Version 1 (test it [here](https://repl.it/xbc)):

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[],[7,8,9,10]]
o = []

mx = len( max(lst, key=len) )
o = [ i.pop(0) for m in range(mx) for i in lst if len(i) != 0 ]

print(o)
```

Version 2 (test it [here](https://repl.it/xbc/1)):

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[],[7,8,9,10]]
o = []

mx = len( max(lst, key=len) )

while mx > 0:
    for i in lst:
        if len(i) != 0:
            o.append( i.pop(0) )
    mx -= 1

print(o)
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 6, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
current_item = list[0]
list.append(list.pop(list.index(list[0])))
```

Current item will always be the next item in list.