# Iterate over all lists inside a list of varied lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iteration, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists. It looks something like this:

```
[
    [4,7,9,10],
    [5,14,55,24,121,56, 89,456, 678],
    [100, 23, 443, 34, 1243,]
    ....
]
```

I want to iterate such that on every iteration I get the respective element of that index from all lists and if the list gets empty, drop it.

For instance, when index will be 0, I want a list that would extend (add) 4 from list 0,5 from list 1, 100 from list 2 (0th index of all list) and if the list gets empty (like list 0 will be fully covered after 3rd iteration, skip it. So iteration should skip this list and move on the next list.

So the output should look like: `[4,5,100, 7, 14, 23, 9, 55, 443, 10, 24, 34, 121, 1243, 56. 89, 456, 678]`

I want a list that extends these values.

Comment: What you have tried till now?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Do you really care about the order? I can't think of an application where this order would be meaningful.

Comment: This is a simple list merge, covered in many places, and (somewhat) supported by `zip_longest`.

Comment: After searching with different terms (my searches yesterday only turned up questions where the input `list`s were all the same length), it looks like this is a proper duplicate of [Take elements from lists, round robin style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31491379/364696). Not sure if voting to reopen just to close as a duplicate is the right move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zip_longest` is problematic, since any solution would silently drop the `fillvalue` if it occurs in the inputs (this can be worked around, but it's always going to be a little hacky).

The most general solution is the `roundrobin` recipe from [the `itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
```

For your input, you'd do something like:

```
mylist = [
    [4,7,9,10],
    [5,14,55,24,121,56, 89,456, 678],
    [100, 23, 443, 34, 1243,]
    ....
]    

print(list(roundrobin(*mylist)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest()` (which is part of the standard library, and is an alternative to the builtin `zip()`, which truncates its output to the shortest of its arguments), to reorder/rotate the lists, and then use a double list comprehension to flatten that output.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

inp = [
    [4,7,9,10],
    [5,14,55,24,121,56, 89,456, 678],
    [100, 23, 443, 34, 1243,]
]

output = [
    elem 
    for tup in zip_longest(*inp)   # if we don't provide a fillvalue... 
    for elem in tup                #   ...missing elements are replaced with None...
    if elem is not None            #   ...which we can filter out
]
# [4, 5, 100, 7, 14, 23, 9, 55, 443, 10, 24, 34, 121, 1243, 56, 89, 456, 678]
```

Comment: I mentioned a hacky solution to fixing this when the input could contain arbitrary values, just figured I'd describe it in a comment here. You can make a cheap, guaranteed "not in the input" value by making an empty object, e.g. `sentinel = object()` (literally `object`; you can make instances of the base class, they're just useless for anything except sentinels). Then you do `zip_longest(*inp, fillvalue=sentinel)` and change the filter condition to `if elem is not sentinel`. Since you make the `sentinel` independently, it can't be in `inp`, so you're guaranteed not to drop any "real" data.

Answer (score 0):

A simple thing to do would be to just convert the given list into a list of equal sized lists by appending with a known value. Then we can iterate over it and add to result only when the element is not the known value.

```
res = []
extra_val = '#'
max_len = float('-inf')
for each in l:
    max_len = max(max_len, len(each))

for each in l:
    if len(each) < max_len:
        n = max_len - len(each)
        extra_list = [extra_val]*n
        each.extend(extra_list)

for i in range(max_len):
    for j in range(len(l)):
        if l[j][i] != extra_val:
            res.append(l[j][i])

print(res)
```

Comment: This is basically the same approach as [Green Cloak Guy's `zip_longest` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64218969/364696), but reimplementing `zip_longest` by hand (making is slower, less maintainable, and imposing some restrictions that `zip_longest` doesn't impose, like inputs being sequences, rather than general iterables).