# How to append element-wise of two lists in Python, where at least one of them is string

Tags: python, string, list, append

I would like to append element-wise of two lists (one in a string format). Suppose:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = ['&','&','\\']
```

The output that I am looking is:

```
['1', '&', '2', '&', '3', '\\']
```

I tried the below code, but the answer is not the right one:

```
[str(x)+y for x,y in zip(a,b)] 
Output: ['1&', '2&', '3\\']
```

Comment: Only real tweak needed relative to the duplicate is to explicitly convert all entries to `str` (which just returns the original `str` when the value is already a `str`, or converts if not).

Comment: It is noted that although the question is also answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946798/interleave-multiple-lists-of-the-same-length-in-python, but at the time of my question I could not find that answer even I searched for different related keywords. It might be the title of the question there or the time, 2011, that the question raised.

Comment: The search terms I used were `interleave python` and `round robin python`, where both "interleave" and "round robin" are ways of describing what you're trying to do. There's actually a lot of other questions like this; I'm personally a fan of the more general solution with the `itertools` `roundrobin` recipe solution (since it works even when the inputs are of varied lengths) seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31491379/364696), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64218927/364696) (a duplicate I didn't find a good duplicate target for until after I'd answered it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
[k for i in zip(map(str, a), b) for k in i]
```

Output :

```
['1', '&', '2', '&', '3', '\\']
```

One limitation of using zip here would be it would iterate up to length of the smallest list, either `a` or `b`. For cases like the following :

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = ['&','&','\\']
```

the above code would produce same result `['1', '&', '2', '&', '3', '\\']` and won't bother to go beyond 3 elements. To circumvent this, you can use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

Comment: Thanks Arkistarvh Kltzuonstev for your answer.